# How to merge two associative arrays

Tags: php, arrays, arraylist

I have two associative arrays like

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2022-01-19
        [1] => 6
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2022-01-20
        [1] => 1
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2022-01-21
        [1] => 1
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2022-01-22
        [1] => 2
    )
)
```

and

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2022-01-17
        [1] => 6
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2022-01-18
        [1] => 1
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2022-01-21
        [1] => 1
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2022-01-23
        [1] => 2
    )
)
```

I need to merge them with the date and want a result array-like below

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2022-01-17
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 6
    )
[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2022-01-18
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 1
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2022-01-19
        [1] => 6
        [2] => 0
    )
[3] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2022-01-20
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 0
    )
[4] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2022-01-21
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
    )
[5] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2022-01-22
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 0
    )
[6] => Array
    (
        [0] => 2022-01-23
        [1] => 0
        [2] => 2
    )
)
```

I tried with the below code but not any success.

```
$final_array = [];
foreach($openTicket as $val){
    $closeTicketNo = 0;
    foreach($closeTicket as $value){
        if($val[0] == $value[0]){
            $closeTicketNo = $value[1];
        }
    }
    $final_array[] = [$val[0],$val[1],$closeTicketNo];
}
```

I get all the elements from the **$openTicket** but not get all the elements from a **$closeTicket** to my result array **$final_array**

Comment: Simple because you have openTicket to closeTicket. You will also need to do closeTicket  to openTicket.

Comment: The term "associative array" means that your keys are meaningful part of the data and cannot be discarded. Did you mean a regular array?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález then it would be a regular array.

Comment: if you could explain the context of the problem that is: why do you need to merge the two arrays, we might recommend a better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code first finds all of the unique dates (using `array_unique`) from the first values in each array (`array_column` fetches the values and `array_merge` puts them into 1 array).

Then it indexes each array by the dates (using `array_column` again).

Finally looping through the unique dates and adding a new element to the output with the values (using `?? 0` so that if no value is present the array is still filled properly)...

```
$dates = array_unique(array_merge(array_column($openTicket, 0), array_column($closedTicket, 0)));
$open = array_column($openTicket, 1, 0);
$closed = array_column($closedTicket, 1, 0);
$finalArray = [];
foreach ($dates as $date) {
    $finalArray[] = [$date, $open[$date] ?? 0, $closed[$date] ?? 0];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like [this](https://onecompiler.com/php/3xscmc4er)

```
$array1 = [
    ['2022-01-19',6],
    ['2022-01-20',1],
    ['2022-01-21',0]
];

$array2 = [
    ['2022-01-17',6],
    ['2022-01-20',2],
    ['2022-01-21',1]
];


function mergeMultiple($array1,$array2){
    foreach($array1 as $item1){
        $mergedArray[$item1[0]] = $item1;
    }

    foreach($array2 as $item2){
        if(isset($mergedArray[$item2[0]])){
             array_push($mergedArray[$item2[0]],$item2[1]);
             $mergedArray[$item2[0]] = $mergedArray[$item2[0]];
        }else{
          $mergedArray[$item2[0]] = $item2;
        }
    }

    return array_values($mergedArray);
}

$mergedArray = mergeMultiple($array1,$array2);
ksort($mergedArray);
print_r($mergedArray);
```